# Menu Bar Popover Opens on Dock Icon Click OSX

Tags: swift, macos

I added a menu bar icon that opens a popover. It works ok but when I close the app via the red cross and try to open the app again with a click on the dock icon it opens the application window (as it should) but also the menu bar popover (which it should not). How can I only open the application window and not the popover when I click on the dock icon? My code that handles the opening of when clicking the dock icon looks like this:

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
    if !flag {
        for window: AnyObject in sender.windows {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today too.
I had the same code so I tried to detect somehow if `window` is popover but failed.
Also I found that if you close main window after start and then click dock icon, if you print `sender.windows`, it shows 3 items (in my case): `<NSStatusBarWindow: 0x101300110>, <NSStatusBarWindow: 0x101108800>, <NSWindow: 0x6080001e0400>`and **opens only main window, without popover**, but if popover was opened once, then clicking on dock icon (when the main window is closed) causes show of both the main window and the popover. And `print(window)` in the `for` cycle now shows 4 items - the last is `<_NSPopoverWindow: 0x1011284b0>`.
And also I printed `popover.isShown`, and it says `false` even after the popover is opened by clicking the dock icon. I couldn't find a way to detect and ignore this particular window.

So the only way I found is to replace

```
    for window: AnyObject in sender.windows {
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
```

with

```
sender.windows[2].makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

because every time the main window appears on the third place
Hope there's a better way and someone will teach us.